# Creating bindings in code (WinRT)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have the following classes

```
ImageViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{ ...
   String Url;
}

AdViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{ ...
    ImageViewModel Image
}
```

The AdViewModel perodicaly changes the Image property (animated Ad).

When I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <Image Source="{Binding Image.Url}"
           Width="{Binding Image.Width}"
           Height="{Binding Image.Height}" />
```

And set the Grids DataContext to an instance of AdViewModel everything works as expected. But I need to create the XAML in C# code to use it elsewhere. Creating a Grid and appending an Image as its child is easy, but how to a create the bindings?

Comment: Why do you need to create it in C# code? Why won't a DataTemplate work? More context around what you're trying to do would help get you to the right answer.

Comment: I need to write a component that another app will call and include the grid with the ad into RichTextBlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easier way. I created the XAML as a UserControl, saved it in a file (Templates\SkyScrapper.xaml). Then instead of creating the controls in C# a just load the XAML File

```
 var _Path = @"Templates\SkyScrapper.xaml";
 var _Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
 var _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync(_Path);
 var _ReadThis = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(_File);

 DependencyObject rootObject = XamlReader.Load(_ReadThis) as DependencyObject;
 var uc = (UserControl)rootObject;
```

and set its DataContext

```
uc.DataContext = ad;
```

There is now no need to create the bindings in C#, they are defined in the XAML file.

Answer (score 8):

try something along the lines of

```
AdViewModel vm = new AdViewModel;      
Binding binding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("Width"),
    Source = vm.Image
};
nameOfGridInXaml.SetBinding(Image.WidthProperty, binding);
```